# Is there something like an OR inside a join in dplyr?

Tags: r, join, dplyr

is it possible to have something like this in `dplyr`?

```
left_join(x, y, by = c("b" = "e") **OR** c("b" = "d"))
```

Comment: Joins dont work that way. You can join on multiple things and then filter afterwards. Its going through asking does b=e, if both were to evaluate to TRUE which should it pull back? if you provide more to what you're looking to do, and provide your dataset, we can figure a way around your problem

Comment: Merge twice, then rbind, unique.